# Showing httpd.exe application error on server

Tags: apache-2.2, php, httpd

I am running an online examination website on my localhost server. When I have attached eight other machines to the LAN to conduct a test, it generate an error message:

```
httpd.exe Application error

The instruction at "0x006fb17f" referenced memory at "0x028a1e20". The memory could not be "Read".

Click on OK to terminate.

Click on Cancel to debug.
```

I am using PHP and MySQL on Windows and XAMPP software installed at my server.

Is this message for my server RAM? Because my server RAM is 512 MB.

I can't understand. Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Either one or more of this:

1. Broken HTTP server
2. Wrong written web application
3. Interference with database server
4. Broken or overheated mainboard, CPU, memory
5. Application firewalls that block certain access
6. Virus scanners that block access to memory
7. whatever ...

Comment: 2. Wrong written web application - it couldn't give such error, if you use only static html and php.
5. Application firewalls that block certain access - this is not firewall problem.

1,3,4,6,7 - this realy may happen.

Comment: @SelivanovPavel Badly written php apps have been known to generate segfaults before - I've seen it several times.

Comment: Hmm... that's strange, PHP is high-level language, it should not have direct access to memory and should have failsafe i/o and system calls.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable causes are:

- broken httpd.exe. Try to replace it with right one
- one of apache modules is broken or compiled for another version. Try disabling `LoadModule` directives and see, if error disappear. Note, that in XAMPP `LoadModule` directives may be placed in many config files, not in one